# Spring Boot - Is it possible to return a File OR xml from web service depending on success?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've been tasked to create a web service that fetches a file from an Azure storage account.

**On sucess**: return the file as the payload

**On error**: return an xml response.

The xml response will contain a copy of the request, error codes and messages etc as the user will need a helpful error message explaining what happened.

I can find instructions for how to return a single object/media type, but not multiple types dependent on condition.

Is this possible?

Comment: Above scenario mentioned is possible. Refer https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Comment: ah ok, so through the exceptions you can return different message types? Thanks I wasn't aware you could return messages to the client from outside the controller!

I also found this building on the callicoder example if it helps anyone https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Answer (score 1):

Solved with an exception handler thanks to Abhijeet's comment
- important to add the contentType or it returns JSON by default

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)
  @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<?> exceptionHandler(MyException e){
      InvoiceArchiveResponse responseObject = e.getResponseObject();
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
              .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/xml"))
              .body(responseObject);
  }
}
```

Thanks!